# Performance on child control MeasureOverride aka UIElement.Measure

Tags: wpf, performance

There's a function to draw over 10k different size rects that i try to speed up.
Rects are divided in groups, and each group may contains over 1k rects.

It takes 30s+ to draw all the rects, about 20s+ on MeasureOverride() and 10s+ on ArrangeOverride(). It takes a lot time to do the foreach, when the base.InternalChildren (aka a group) has hundreds even thousands of rects.

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size availableSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
        foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
        {
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.Measure(availableSize);
            }
        }
        return new Size();
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in base.InternalChildren)
        {                
            if (!element.IsMeasureValid)
                continue;

            var x = GetX(element);
            var y = GetY(element);

            var width = element.DesiredSize.Width;
            var height = element.DesiredSize.Height;
            element.Arrange(new Rect(x - width * 0.5, y - height * 0.5, width, height));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

this derived class from Panel has a lot function on it, I can't simply replace it with a rectangle or border. So I try to do the foreach out of it, like this:

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var list = base.InternalChildren.Cast<UIElement>().ToList();
        Size availableSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
        MeeasureTest(list, constraint);

        return new Size();
    }

    private void MeeasureTest(List<UIElement> list, Size availableSize)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();           

        //Parallel.ForEach(list, element =>
        //{
        //    if (element != null && !element.IsArrangeValid)
        //    {
        //        element.Measure(availableSize);
        //    }
        //});

        foreach (UIElement element in list)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
            {
                if (element != null)
                {
                    element.Measure(availableSize);
                }
            });
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Measure " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " - " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

It turns out, if I use Parallel.Foreach, it'll cause a thread exception. if I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke inside the foreach, it'll execute soon. BUT all the rects still need 30s+ to be shown, i guess in the UI thread it still need to be measured one by one.

Am I trying the wrong direction? Can anyone give some tips pls?

Comment: Have you considered using a [DrawingVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)?

Comment: I'd also suggest you consider writeablebitmapex. You could maybe multi thread calculations for the size of the rectangles. Build it and freeze on a non ui thread. Maybe the groups could be different bitmaps.

Comment: No matter the rendering technique you use, iterating over 10k+ items will consume time. There is not much you can do except tweaking your general design. Maybe you can cache data or your clusters to avoid iterating over all of them on each measure and arrange pass. Maybe you can implement virtualization to only handle visible objects in case not all objects are always visible in the current viewport.

Comment: Maybe you can partition your calculations to parallelize calculations and creation of rendering objects, for example each cluster on a separate thread, or use a multi threaded Producer Consumer pattern. This job is obviously not depending on any order of processing, therefore parallel processing is really easy.

Comment: For this reason you need a rendering technique that allows creation on a background thread (to prevent cross-thread exceptions). This means you could use drawing objects like `GeometryDrawing` or the solution suggested by Andy. It depends on your requirements. [Drawing Objects Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/drawing-objects-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: thanks for everyone's help. it's quite an old app and maybe it's time to redesign it now. i'll have meetings with team leader about it. thanks very much again.